# Formal equivalent of "fast forward to today"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm trying to think of a formal word or phrase that I can use to substitute this line at the beginning of a sentence: "Fast forward to today, ...". For context:

> At its onset, the industry had little in terms of standardized rules
>   and metrics. ______________, progress towards a more unified
>   regulatory framework has made much headway.

"Fast forward to today" seems to be a great fit for flow, but it is not of the writing persona deemed suitable for my writing. What formal equivalents should I consider?

Comment: What's wrong with using just **today**? I don't understand the necessity of the *fast forward to* part. Is there some meaning you're trying to convey with it that just *today* does not capture?

Comment: @KannE, I agree. My English instructor always told us to be as clear and concise as possible. This may be one of the reasons the Gettysburg Address was so great.

Comment: @KannE Thanks for going the extra mile, I am fond of the Hemingway style, though I can't always do it justice. I will be sure to adjust the second part.

Comment: How about "Since then"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Shifting our focus to the present day, (we see that)
>   progress...

That would keep the element of change denoted by *fast forward*

Comment: Thanks, corrected.